# Add Arbitrary Attribute to SQL Query from Joins Record without WHERE clause (Active record)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to create an attribute in my select statement that depends on whether or not an association exists. I'm not sure if it's possible with a single query, and the goal is to not have to iterate a list afterward.

Here is the structure.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :projects, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Knowing a project, the goal of the query is to return ALL users and include on them a new attribute call subscribed - denoting whether or not they are subscribed.

non-working code (pseudo code):

```
  project = Project.find_by(name: 'has_subscribers')

  query = 'users.*, (subscriptions.project_id = ?) AS subscribed'

  users = User.includes(:subscriptions).select(query, project.id)

  user.first.subscribed
  # => true or false
```

I'm open to whether or not there is a better way of going about this. However, the information is:

- You know the project record.
- You query a list of ALL users
- Each user record has a `subscribed` attribute, denoting whether its
  subscribed to the given project

---

#### Solution:

I was able to figure out a straight forward solution using the bool_or aggregate method. Coalesce ensures that the value returned is `false` instead of `nil`, should no subscriptions exists.

```
query = "users.*, COALESCE(bool_or(subscriptions.project_id = '#{project_id}'::uuid), false) as subscribed"

User.left_outer_joins(:subscriptions)
  .select(query)
  .group('users.id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can do this:

```
User.joins(:projects).select(Arel.star, Subscription.arel_table[:project_id])
```

Which will result in a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *, "subscriptions"."project_id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "subscriptions"."user_ud" = "users"."id";
```

---

If you want to specify a specific project (i.e. use an expression), you can do it with Arel like this:

```
User.joins(:projects).select(Arel.star, Subscription.arel_table[:project_id].eq(42))
```

Unfortunately, you won't have a column name alias, and you can't call `as` on an Arel::Nodes::Equality instance. I don't know enough about the internals of Arel to have a way out of that box. But you can do this if you want the composability of Arel (e.g. if this is going to be something that needs to work with multiple models or columns):

```
User.joins(:projects).select(Arel.star, Subscription.arel_table[:project_id].eq(42).to_sql + " as has_project")
```

This is a bit clunky, but it works and provides a `user.has_project` method that returns a boolean. You can pretty it up like so:

```
class User
  scope :with_project_status, lambda do |project_id|
    has_project = 
      Subscription.arel_table[:project_id].
        eq(project_id).to_sql + " as has_project"

    joins(:projects).select(Arel.star, has_project)
  end
end

User.with_project_status(42).where(active: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was trying to use arel_table but couldn't figure it out. Would you mind helping me figure out how to get the attribute set to whether or not the user is subscribed to a given project? As if I could do something like `.....select(Arel.star, "subscriptions.project_id = #{project.id} AS subscribed", Subscription.arel_table[:project_id])`

Comment: @SebastianScholl Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: This is super cool. Thanks so much for taking the time to help out and detail everything! Worked like a charm.  It's worth the clunk :)